# Implementing Partial Document Updates in MongoDB with Kafka Message and MongoDB Sink Connector

Tags: mongodb

partial updates to MongoDB documents using Kafka messages and the MongoDB Sink Connector. What considerations should I keep in mind when designing the Kafka messages to ensure seamless updates on the MongoDB side? Are there any potential challenges or limitations I should be aware of while using this setup? Any advice or examples from those who have successfully implemented this integration

here is my mongo document
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "64c891487aff984657fda73d"
},
"customer": {
"last_name": "bee",
"unique_id": "abc234",
"first_name": "noo",
"email": "abc234@email.com"
}
}

need to update only first_name.

here is my kafka message look likes
echo '{"unique_id": "abc234", "first_name": "testing"}' | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic customer.profile.updates

after update, it should be

{
"_id": {
"$oid": "64c891487aff984657fda73d"
},
"customer": {
"last_name": "bee",
"unique_id": "abc234",
"first_name": "testing",
"email": "abc234@email.com"
}
}